# Elementor - Open popup with dynamic content on post grid custom template content click

Tags: wordpress, popup, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I've been struggling on popup which displays dynamic content of the post along with ACF fields from a dynamic post grid.
The popup does open, but the content on it is not of the post clicked in the grid, but it's of the page where the post list is being displayed.
Also, the page gets refreshed. ;(

[image]

[image: open popup]

Searching for solution for quite a long time, but still unable to crack it.